# If I buy CPUs for my server, do I have to buy a "matching pair"?

Tags: central-processing-unit

Can I purchase two identical CPUs say from different websites?  I was told they need to be a "matching pair" but I can't find any evidence to support that.  Will I encounter any problems from buying two individual CPUs that aren't a "pair"?

In case it matters, this is the motherboard: https://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1u/1028/sys-1028gq-tr.cfm

Comment: `Can I purchase two identical CPUs say from different websites?` - Why would you do that? Why would you not buy both of them from the same vendor?

Comment: It was a hypothetical scenario to help ensure my question was clear.  But if you really want an answer, what if one ebay seller only had 1 for really cheap so I wanted to buy it and then the second one from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to buy two identical CPUs. That means they must be the same processor model and stepping. They do not have to be sold by the same vendor.

Comment: Thank you. I was suspicious when I was told this but I wanted to make sure and couldn't find any discussions online.